# How use JWT Bearer Scheme when working with WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, xunit

I have a working web API that I recently updated to use JWT auth and, while it is working when I run it normally, I can't seem to get my integration tests to work.

I wanted to start working on integrating a token generation option for my integration tests, but I can't even get them to throw a 401.

When I run any of my preexisting integration tests that work without JWT in the project, I'd expect to get a 401 since I don't have any auth info, but am actually getting a `System.InvalidOperationException : Scheme already exists: Bearer` error.

I'd assume this is happening because of the way that `WebApplicationFactory` works by running its `ConfigureWebHost` method runs after the Startup class' `ConfigureServices` method and when i put a breakpoint on my jwt service, it does indeed get hit twice, but given that this is how `WebApplicationFactory` is built, I'm not sure what the recommended option here is. Of note, even when I remove one of the services I still get the error:

```cs
var serviceDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(JwtBearerHandler));
services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
```

My `WebApplicationFactory` is based on the eshopwebapi factory:

```cs
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<StartupTesting>
    {
        // checkpoint for respawning to clear the database when spinning up each time
        private static Checkpoint checkpoint = new Checkpoint
        {
            
        };

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseEnvironment("Testing");

            builder.ConfigureServices(async services =>
            {
                // Create a new service provider.
                var provider = services
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                // Add a database context (LabDbContext) using an in-memory 
                // database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<LabDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(provider);
                });

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
                // context (ApplicationDbContext).
                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<LabDbContext>();

                    // Ensure the database is created.
                    db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    try
                    {
                        await checkpoint.Reset(db.Database.GetDbConnection());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }).UseStartup<StartupTesting>();
        }

        public HttpClient GetAnonymousClient()
        {
            return CreateClient();
        }
    }
```

This is my service registration:

```cs
    public static class ServiceRegistration
    {
        public static void AddIdentityInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = configuration["JwtSettings:Authority"];
                    options.Audience = configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"];
                });
            
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CanReadPatients", 
                    policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "patients.read"));
                options.AddPolicy("CanAddPatients", 
                    policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "patients.add"));
                options.AddPolicy("CanDeletePatients", 
                    policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "patients.delete"));
                options.AddPolicy("CanUpdatePatients", 
                    policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "patients.update"));
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is my integration test (that I would expect to currently throw a 401):

```cs
public class GetPatientIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
    { 
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory _factory;

        public GetPatientIntegrationTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetPatients_ReturnsSuccessCodeAndResourceWithAccurateFields()
        {
            var fakePatientOne = new FakePatient { }.Generate();
            var fakePatientTwo = new FakePatient { }.Generate();

            var appFactory = _factory;
            using (var scope = appFactory.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LabDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                context.Patients.AddRange(fakePatientOne, fakePatientTwo);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var client = appFactory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });

            var result = await client.GetAsync("api/Patients")
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<IEnumerable<PatientDto>>>(responseContent).Data;

            // Assert
            result.StatusCode.Should().Be(200);
            response.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(fakePatientOne, options =>
                options.ExcludingMissingMembers());
            response.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(fakePatientTwo, options =>
                options.ExcludingMissingMembers());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Hey I saw your post when I was looking for the same answer. I solved it by putting the following code in the ConfigureWebHost method of my WebApplicationFactory:

```
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(
        IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection =>
        {

        });
   
        // Overwrite registrations from Startup.cs
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(serviceCollection =>
        {
            var authenticationBuilder = serviceCollection.AddAuthentication();
            authenticationBuilder.Services.Configure<AuthenticationOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.SchemeMap.Clear();
                ((IList<AuthenticationSchemeBuilder>) o.Schemes).Clear();
            });
        });
    }
```

I know I'm four months late, but I hope you still have any use for it.

Comment: Also I used this library for the fake authentication: https://github.com/webmotions/fake-authentication-jwtbearer. Maybe also some use to you.

Comment: I did the same as @weretiger